# Does Square correctly inherits from Rectangle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function Rectangle(length, width) {
    this.length = length;
    this.width = width;
}

Rectangle.prototype.getArea = function() {
    return this.length * this.width;
};

function Square(size) {
    this.length = size;
    this.width = size;
}

Square.prototype = new Rectangle();
```

That's my code.

Does Square correctly inherits from Rectangle? Please suggest me the changes to  do it correctly.

New to Inheritance and prototypes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does Square correctly inherits from Rectangle?

No, but it's close. Here are the changes for `Square`:

```
function Square(size) {
    Rectangle.call(this, size, size);
}

Square.prototype = Object.create(Rectangle.prototype);
Square.prototype.constructor = Square;
```

Calling `Rectangle` to create `Square`'s prototype is a sadly-common anti-pattern; what if it actually does something with the arguments we're not giving it when doing that?

Instead, you create an object that uses `Rectangle.prototype` as its prototype, using `Object.create`. Then you update the `constructor` property on that prototype so it's pointing at the right function. Then when you actually have an object to initialize (e.g., in the `Square` function), you call `Rectangle` from `Square` to initialize its bit, then do any further init `Square` needs afterward.

Since it's a bit verbose, before I switched to ES2015 `class` syntax I used a helper script for this called [`Lineage`](https://code.google.com/p/lineagejs/). That bit creating the prototype can be isolated into a function, which also gives us an opportunity to support IE8 by working around the fact it's missing `Object.create`:

```
function derivePrototype(parent, child) {
    var proto, ctor;
    if (Object.create) {
        proto = Object.create(parent.prototype);
    } else {
        ctor = function ctor() { };       // * See note
        ctor.prototype = parent.prototype;
        proto = new ctor;
        ctor = null;
    }
    proto.constructor = child;
    return proto;
}
```

Then

```
Square.prototype = derivePrototype(Rectangle, Square);
```

* `ctor = function ctor() { };` creates two functions on IE8 ([details](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/09/double-take.html)), but it's harmless as neither is retained, and the function does get a name.

---

Or of course, you can use ES2015+:

```
class Rectangle {
    constructor(length, width) {
        this.length = length;
        this.width = width;
    }

    getArea() {
        return this.length * this.width;
    }
}

class Square extends Rectangle {
    constructor(size) {
        super(size, size);
    }
}
```

All major modern browsers support this native now (in 2019), but of course, older browsers like Internet Explorer don't (not even IE11), so if you need to target older browsers, you'd need to transpile (for instance, with something like [Babel](https://babeljs.io)).

Comment: Thankyou. New to these :)

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ: np (btw, finished updating the answer slightly seconds after you posted). The pattern you used shows up a *lot*.